# Java How can I get my sprite to update according to keypresses

Tags: java, input, key, sprite, updates

In my player update method I change the sprites according to which key was pressed (left, right, up, or down). What I'm trying to achieve here is if the user is holding down the left key, then presses up, down, or right, the player will move in that direction and change sprites accordingly, and same with all the other directions.  The code I have now is just a basic check depending on which key was pressed and changes sprites and position accordingly. But as I was running a test program I realized that if the user is pressing up, then wants to go another direction, the user has to release the up button before the sprite moves in the other direction. What I want is if the user is holding the up button, then they want to go left, the user can just press left and that's the direction the player will go, even without releasing the up button.

my code so far is:

```
if (input.up) {
            ya--;
            animSprite = up;
        } else if (input.down) {
            ya++;
            animSprite = down;
        } else if (input.left) {
            xa--;
            animSprite = right;
        } else if (input.right) {
            xa++;
            animSprite = right;
        }
```

I tried adding a boolean variable to my Keyboard class that was true when a user pressed any button, and when button is released it was false, and tried saying:

```
if (input.up && !keyPressed) // user would move up only if a key wasn't pressed.
```

But that resulted in running that condition, but then the keyPressed variable became true so it wouldn't run the code.

Comment: Start here: https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835

Comment: That helped! I ended up using the ArrayList to store the string of the keycode. Then everytime a key is pressed, if it doesn't exist in the arraylist, then i clear the list and add the new key in there, therefore only allowing one direction at a time.

Comment: Glad it helped. It's a very good tutorial for beginners. I used it to learn about javafx game development.